# C# - Duplicate ContextMenuStrip Items into another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have two ContextMenuStrip(s) in a Windows Form Application, one of them has 3 items and the other one has none.

Let's suppose this:

```
ContextMenuStrip c1 = new ContextMenuStrip();
ContextMenuStrip c2;
```

c1 has 3 `ToolStripMenuItems`, c2 is the `ContextMenuStrip` destination where c1 items should be duplicated.

I tried to write this:

```
c2 = new ContextMenuStrip(c1.Container);
```

but it gives me an `ArgumentNullException` because `c1.Container` is Equal to `null`.

I cant figure out how to solve this, can you help me?

Ps.
I would `new ToolStripMenuItem`(s), no references

and

`while` or `foreach` loops solutions are not the best way to do this.

Thank you :)

Comment: You have some code somewhere that creates the ContextMenuStrip object.  Call it again.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, have a function that creates the ContextMenuStrip and call it each time a new menu is needed

```
Func<ContextMenuStrip> newContextMenuStrip = () => { 
    var c = new ContextMenuStrip();
    c.Items.Add("item 1");
    c.Items.Add("item 2");
    c.Items.Add("item 3");
    return c;
};

var c1 = newContextMenuStrip();
var c2 = newContextMenuStrip();
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm gonna try this, I'll let you know

Comment: This is an incredible solution and it works perfectly. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I have had the same issue in the past and found a reasonably simple solution.

Say your toolStripMenuItem is declared as 'TSMI_open' in a context menu,
you can effectively hot-swap it between context menus as they open.
Something like this:

```
void Context1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
     Context1.Items.Insert(0, TSMI_open);
}

void Context2_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
     Context2.Items.Insert(0, TSMI_open);
}
```

The menu item will appear on both menus when seamlessly, and will cause no errors if the same menu is opened twice consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `ContextMenuStrip` and add the `Item`s (not the `Container` of `c1` to the new menu:

```
c2 = new ContextMenuStrip();
c2.Items.AddRange(c1.Items);
```

---

But note that this does not *duplicate* the items. The *same item instances* are now in both menus.

If you want to clone them, this is rather complicated as you have to take care of the specific types of the items, the properties you want to clone and especially the event handlers.

A simple example could be:

```
c2.Items.AddRange(c1.Items.OfType<ToolStripItem>()
                           .Select(item => new ToolStripMenuItem(item.Text))
                           .OfType<ToolStripItem>().ToArray());
```

The second `OfType` is necessary to avoid a co-variant array conversion from `ToolStripMenuItem[]` to `ToolStripItem[]` which is expected by `AddRange()`.

---

And a side note: [`Container`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.container(v=vs.110).aspx) is the component that *contains* the menu (thatswhy it's `null` when the menu is not shown) and not the thing the menu keeps its items in.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this gives me same instances, but not new "Cloned" instance.. but thank you :)

Comment: @EdoardoChiabra To clone the items is a little more complicated and I don't think you can do it "in one line". First you have to care about the specific item type, second you need to know which properties you want to clone, and this is specifically complicated for the `Click` event handlers.

Comment: I know that "one line solution" is uthopian, what do you suggest about it?
A loop?

Comment: @EdoardoChiabra this is a little too broad to answer (at least in comments). It depends a lot on the properties you want to clone and where these information come from (especially event handlers). I know too little of what you are really trying to achieve, e.g. _why_ you want to clone them at all.

Comment: @EdoardoChiabra added a little example of what could be possible, but it clones only the `Text` property and generates only `ToolStripMenuItem`s, no other `ToolStripItem` derivate.

Comment: Because, during Runtime, the program creates some buttons. Every button needs a ContextMenuStrip, duplicated from c1 model.
Than, code sets the `Enabled` property for each ToolStripMenuItem in ContextMenuStrip associated to a button.
Every ToolStripMenuItem has a Click EventHandler, but actually I don't really mind about it right now!